# Is there a way to apply gruvbox color scheme for standard text files?

Tags: vim

Like, all program files are syntax highled by this plugin for vim. But my I/O files are standard text files.

So, how to apply colour scheme for text files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "standard text file". `foo.c` and `bar.json` are both "text files" but:

- their file extension and possibly various other properties and heuristics allow text editors to decide if they are `C` files, or `JSON` files, or whatever,
- their content follows a specific syntax that text editors know and use for syntax highlighting.

If your text editor can't figure out the filetype of a given file `baz`, then it will have a hard time highlighting its syntax.

So you have four scenarios…

1. It is possible to detect the type of the file and its content follows a specific syntax.

   You need to tell Vim how to detect the filetype, see `:help new-filetype`, and either assign it an existing syntax, see `:help 'syntax'`, or create your own, see `:help syntax.txt`.
2. It is not possible to detect the type of the file but its content follows a specific syntax.

   You need to assign a filetype manually, see `:help 'filetype'`, and either assign it an existing syntax, see `:help 'syntax'`, or create your own, see `:help syntax.txt`.
3. It is possible to detect the type of the file but its content doesn't follow a specific syntax.

   Well, there is no syntax to highlight so it's GAME OVER.
4. It is not possible to detect the type of the file and its content doesn't follow a specific syntax.

   GAME OVER again.

Comment: Okay, how do I tell gruvbox plugin to apply colour scheme to .text, .in, .out files?

Comment: You don't tell anything to gruvbox as it doesn't care about file extensions, filetypes or even syntax. You follow `:help new-filetype`, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Okay, there are a hell a lot of filetypes in syntax folder. Is there anything basic in there? Like, can be applied to general files? I want to apply them to my input & output files, those often contain some numbers and strings. No keywords or nothing.

Comment: "General files" is just like "standard text files": it means nothing regarding *syntax*. Either your file has a specific, predictable syntax, in which case syntax highlighting can happen, or it hasn't. Only *you* know your file's eventual syntax so only *you* can determine which built-in syntax script is similar enough.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for making me figure out that finally, now I just need to remove ugly looking color scheme for i/o files.